# MYSQL get data BETWEEN AND condition OR condition

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause, between

I am trying to fetch data as json between two id's which have userid either `Get['id']` or user who follow `Get['id']` from other **Table**.

My URL is - http://localhost/aditya/m/login?id=1&&start=6

```
if(isset($_GET['start'])) {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE (id BETWEEN '".$_GET['start']."' AND '".$_GET['start']."' + 3) AND userid = '".$_GET['id']."' OR userid IN (SELECT userid FROM frndlist WHERE followers = '".$_GET['id']."') "; }
```

Data are coming in between id 6 to 9 but why 5 is also coming ??
(postid in json as id) !!

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "like":"</a>",
         "like_no":"0</span>",
         "time":"th , ",
         "pro_pic":"members/boykiller654@gmail.com/WIN_20150115_125206.JPG",
         "userid":"2",
         "fname":"Aditya",
         "lname":"Raj",
         "share":"innovation",
         "title":"tasty",
         "postid":"5",
         "postimg":"http://192.168.43.142/aditya/mfoodora/members/boykiller654@gmail.com/download-371493367.jpg",
         "desc":"hejgfiyrivbgdyvdgvgjdehuidkjvdakllj",
         "comm_no":"0",
         "comment":"</a>",
         "add":"</a>"
      },
      {
         "like":"</a>",
         "like_no":"0</span>",
         "time":"th , ",
         "pro_pic":"members/boykiller654@gmail.com/WIN_20150115_125206.JPG",
         "userid":"2",
         "fname":"Aditya",
         "lname":"Raj",
         "share":"trick",
         "title":"tasty",
         "postid":"6",
         "postimg":"",
         "desc":"hejgfiyrivbgdyvdgvgjdehuidkjvdakllj",
         "comm_no":"0",
         "comment":"</a>",
         "add":"</a>"
      },
      {
         "like":"</a>",
         "like_no":"1</span>",
         "time":"Mar 24th",
         "pro_pic":"members/boykiller654@gmail.com/WIN_20150115_125206.JPG",
         "userid":"2",
         "fname":"Aditya",
         "lname":"Raj",
         "share":"recipe",
         "title":"tasty",
         "postid":"7",
         "postimg":"",
         "desc":"hejgfiyrivbgdyvdgvgjdehuidkjvdakllj",
         "comm_no":"0",
         "comment":"</a>",
         "add":"</a>"
      },
      {
         "like":"</a>",
         "like_no":"0</span>",
         "time":"Mar 25th",
         "pro_pic":"members/aditraj2@gmail.com/WIN_20150115_140702.JPG",
         "userid":"1",
         "fname":"Joe",
         "lname":"Harris",
         "share":"Trick",
         "title":"Chicken Hyderabadi Biryani",
         "postid":"9",
         "postimg":"http://192.168.43.142/aditya/mfoodora/members/aditraj2@gmail.com/chocolate-mint-bar-1231354420.jpg",
         "desc":"So , here it goes .. It's a very hybrid biryani especially found in India . Vey famous and tasty but...Read More</a>",
         "comm_no":"1",
         "comment":"</a>",
         "add":"</a>"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your schema and some sample response

Comment: ok, you told us what you're trying to do.  Now what's the problem?

Comment: Getting Wrong answer , BETWEEN is not working..

Comment: Try `echo` on this and then paste that additionally into the question. As it stands we can't read the query easily. Also, please try that in your database directly (e.g. MySQL on the console, or phpMyAdmin). It also has a SQL injection vuln, which you must fix before going live.

Comment: (I would recommend writing your SQL strings over many lines, incidentally, so as to make them much more readable both in your code and when you paste them here).

Comment: @Tom: the quote device `>` is not really suitable for JSON strings. I suggest running badly formatted JSON [through a formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and then pasting as code (of course, the OP should do this, but still).

Comment: @AdityaRaj: your question is not very clear, and has needed quite a bit of repair to make it more readable. I have reluctantly downvoted. We still need to see the SQL without the PHP, as I have already advised.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping your `OR` statement together by putting it in parenthesis.

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE (id BETWEEN '1' AND '500' + 5) AND 
(userid = 'testuserid' OR 
userid IN (SELECT user FROM frndlist WHERE followers = 'tom') )
```

Answer (score 0):

AND has higher precedence than OR.

```
WHERE cond1 AND cond2 OR cond3
```

is interpreted as

```
WHERE ( cond1 AND cond2 ) OR cond3
```

Just like `3 * 5 + 4` is interpreted as `(3 * 5) + 4`

So, as long as the last condition is true, the row will be included.